# How to create a fixed navbar inside a sidenav with Materializecss

Tags: materialize

I am using MaterializeCSS and would like to create a sidenav but with the navbar in it that is fixed so when content of sidenav is scrolled then the navbar remains at the top.

I have given this a go but with no luck.  I can get a navbar inside the sidenav with no problem and following the instructions on the MaterializeCss site I am making it fixed but it still scrolls off the top of the page